# Interpretations and signature in first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Trying to figure out precise definitions.

I have a language $\mathscr{L_1}$.
From that language I write a set of sentences $\Sigma_1$.
Then I built a model of $\Sigma_1$, I called it $\mathscr{A_1}$

Then I add a new constant into the original language $\mathscr{L_1}$. I call the new language $\mathscr{L_2}$.
I create a new sentence $\phi$ that uses that new constant. I add $\phi$ into $\Sigma_1$ and I call this new set $\Sigma_2$.
Then I built a model of $\Sigma_2$, I called it $\mathscr{A_2}$.

$\mathscr{A_2}$ is a model of $\Sigma_1$?

When we say that an structure $\mathscr{A}$ interprets a language $\mathscr{L_1}$ with signature ${a,b,c,d}$, can we automatically assume that the very same structure $\mathscr{A}$ interprets a language $\mathscr{L_2}$ with signature ${a,b}$?

FOLLOW-UP:

I have a language $\mathscr{L_1}$.
From that language I write a set of sentences $\Sigma_1$.
Then I built a model of $\Sigma_1$, I called it $\mathscr{A_1}$

Then I add a new constant $c$ into the original language $\mathscr{L_1}$. I call the new language $\mathscr{L_2}$. I add the sentence $\{\exists{x} : x=c\}$ into $\Sigma_1$ and I call this new set $\Sigma_2$.

Is it trivial that a model of $\Sigma_2$ exists?

If a model of $\Sigma_2$ exists let's call it $\mathscr{A_2}$, $\mathscr{A_2}$ is a model of $\Sigma_1$.

But it is true that $\mathscr{A_1}$ must be a model of $\Sigma_2$?

When two structures are the same?

The domain of the interpretation functional is an essential part of the structure?

<$\mathbb{S} , \hat{c}$> is diferent from <$\mathbb{S}$> even when $\hat{c}\in\mathbb{S}$?

Comment: Yes, if $\Sigma_2$ is made of $\Sigma_1$ plus a new sentence $\phi$ and $\mathscr A_2$ is a model of $\Sigma_2$, this means that $\mathscr A_2$ satisfies **all** sentences of $\Sigma_2$ and thus also all sentences of $\Sigma_1$

Comment: And yes, if $\mathscr A$ interpret **all** non-logical symbols of $\mathscr L_1$, it interpret also a subset of that set of non-logical symbols.